# WSO2 Inbound Endpoint creation type required for AmazonSQS Streaming Inbound Endpoint Operations

Tags: wso2, amazon-sqs, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.0 for development. I am trying [AmazonSQS Streaming Inbound Endpoint Operations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+AmazonSQS+Streaming+Inbound+Endpoint+Operations).

[image: Inbound EP Types]

In above image , selected HTTP as Creation Type. after giving below code inside this Inbound Endpoint, all are gone , default parameters only showing when i reopen the same file.

Inbound Endpoint code:

```
    <inboundEndpoint
     class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.amazonsqs.AmazonSQSPollingConsumer"
     name="AmazonSQS" onError="fault" sequence="request" suspend="false">
     <parameters>
         <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
         <parameter name="interval">2000</parameter>
         <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
         <parameter name="waitTime">19</parameter>
         <parameter name="maxNoOfMessage">10</parameter>
        <parameter name="destination">URL of the Amazon SQS Queue</parameter>
         <parameter name="accessKey">your accessKey</parameter>
         <parameter name="secretKey">your secretKey</parameter>
         <parameter name="attributeNames">attributeName1,contentType</parameter>
         <parameter name="contentType">text/plain</parameter> </parameters>
         <parameter name="autoRemoveMessage">true</parameter>
     </parameters>
 </inboundEndpoint>
```

Code after reopen the same file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="AmazonSQS" protocol="http" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="inbound.http.port">8000</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.worker.pool.size.core">400</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.worker.pool.size.max">500</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.worker.thread.keep.alive.sec">60</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.worker.pool.queue.length">-1</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.thread.id">PassThroughInboundWorkerPool</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

PS: Amazon SQS Connector added in ESB Config project. while working in Developer Studio, same HTTP Creation type is working fine. No issues at all.

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? or any other type is required to poll data from Amazon SQS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.0, by using Inbound Endpoint Creation Type as **"Custom"** ,achieved AmazonSQS Streaming Inbound Endpoint Operations polling.

PS: In WSO2 Developer studio HTTP as creation type is works fine.